# Stack of 20 cards. Distribute to 4 people randomly...... What is the probability each person ends up with the same number of cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Stack of 20 cards. Distribute to 4 people randomly.
Assume that each person does not have t be dealt the same number of card.
 What is the probability each person ends up with the same number of cards?

Comment: The hardest part for me in the counting. I have no idea how to count the total number of possible distribution of cards one can hand to these people randomy.

Comment: Hint: How many owners can each of the 20 cards have?

Answer (score 0):

To find the total possible number of distributions of cards (**hint**)

- how many people could receive the first card?
- how many people could receive the second card?
- . . .
- how many people could receive the twentieth card?

To find the number of distributions in which every person receives the same number of cards,

- in how many ways could the first person receive five cards?
- in how many ways could the second person then receive five cards?
- . . .
- in how many ways could the fourth person then receive five cards?

Comment: I think we're assuming not all the cards have to be distributed.

Comment: Perhaps you should make it clear in the question that not all cards need to be used.  In any case very much the same approach will work.  Add an extra person called "Nobody" and distribute all the cards to five people instead of four.  And for the second part, consider also the cases that the four "real" people receive four cards each, or three, or two, or one, or none.